# Swift: Importing Custom Framework - Use of Unresolved Identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

After moving some code into an external framework I've been trying to import and use the framework in my app. I've added the framework as a dependency in my app.

My framework is called DiceKit. In one of the classes, just to test things out, I've added `import DiceKit` to the top of my file. This is not throwing any errors.

When I try to access the classes that should be in the framework, I get a Use of Unresolved Identifier error.

```
import UIKit
import DiceKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println (Die(12).roll())   // `Die` doesn't exist at compile time
    }
}
```

What could be causing the classes in the framework to not be compiled? I have made sure that all the classes and methods are marked with public and I haven't changed any build settings from the default in my framework.

I'm using XCode 6.3 Beta

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your external framework objective-C? have you made  bridging header?

Comment: The external framework was also written in Swift. There is a single header file in there which was created by XCode, DiceKit.h. Would I still need the bridging header in this case?

Comment: Add the declaration of the Dice class. I assume it's not declared as public. Also note that using swift code as a framework has still some drawbacks atm, especially as it is essential that the embedded Swift versions must be the same (in both the app and the framework), so it might be better atm to just include the code in your project, instead only the framework.

Comment: @MikeLischke, where should I add the declaration of which dice class? All of the classes in the framework are marked as public.    It is interesting though about the swift code requiring the same version numbers. It's just another reason that Swift doesn't seem 100% ready to use.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about the declaration. I meant that you should add it to the question text so we can see if things like the public scope is set. But as you said it is declared public already. No idea currently what else could be wrong.

Comment: Btw, have you tried the XCode 6 release already (Version 6.3.1 (6D1002) is what I'm using atm.)?

Comment: I was having this problem; I solved it by adding my .swift files to the Framework's Compile Sources (and not the Headers) under Build Phases. Then Xcode recognized them and I could use them as normal.

Answer (score 6):

In your **DiceKit**  custom framework

You should declare your **Die** class as **public**.

**public** **public** **public** all the things! Or at least, the things that others need to use from the framework.

Comment: I'm downvoting because the OP already mentioned that the class was definitely public. This answer, as is, does not seem an improvement